# "Foundations" as title of an introductory section

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm currently reviewing an academic paper written by a non-native English writer.  The paper has an introductory section titled "Foundations" which contains definitions of later used terminology as well as short summaries of relevant subjects.

**Does "Foundations" appropriately describe such a section?** I was under the impression that it's mostly used to mean either a part of a building or the "assumed common" knowledge of a whole science branch ("foundations of mathematics" for example).  I've seen such sections being titled for example as "Background". Would that be more appropriate?

Comment: Note: I'm asking this here instead of on Academia because it's really just about the word choice, not the usefulness of the section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be the equivalent of "Grundlagen" from German in a scientific paper?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133818/what-would-be-the-equivalent-of-grundlagen-from-german-in-a-scientific-paper)

Comment: In a mathematical document, this might be "Terminology" or "Background", yes. "Foundations" is reasonable except in certain cases: for example, the word "foundations" has a specific mathematical meaning as a field of study.

Answer (score 1):

(Native speaker.) I'm not an academic, but "Foundations" seems reasonable.

One of [Webster's definitions of "foundation"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundation) is:

> a basis (such as a tenet, principle, or axiom) upon which something stands or is supported

So, sure, that definitely applies to "foundations of mathematics" - but it could also refer to the principles or ideas that a single paper stands upon. Even a tiny building has a foundation. ;)

I would interpret these two statements as meaning the same thing:

> You need a foundation in linear algebra to understand this paper.
>
> You need a background in linear algebra to understand this paper.

Of course, if "Background" is the general standard for such a section, that's probably the better choice. But, absent a standard, "Foundations" doesn't seem wrong to me.